# Accessing Encrypted SQL Server database through a web-based application

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, security, encryption

I have secured a database within SQL Server Instance on my local machine using Netlib Encryptionizer. I can access the database by securing my SQL Server instance using the same password as encrypted database password otherwise it is unaccessible through SQL Server which is what i want.

However, I want a web-based application to access my encrypted database even when my SQL Server Instance is unsecured.

Can anyone help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old thread so I don't know if you still monitor it. I'm from NetLib Security. Can I suggest you open up a support incident here?
https://netlibsecurity.com and then click Support.